# Mysql multi table delete effect all but one table

Tags: mysql

I used the following sql syntax to delete from several tables. The result is that the data is erased from table 2-4 but not in table 1 (no errors)

```
DELETE table1, table2, table3, table4 FROM table2 
JOIN table1 ON table1.id = table2.deviceid 
JOIN table3 ON table3.deviceid = table2.deviceid  
JOIN table4 ON table4.device_id = table2.deviceid
WHERE table2.deviceid = 1;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your syntax is correct.  However, I am not a fan of multi-table delete.  I think four simple delete statements are much clearer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Well, If it was correct it would have worked, isn't it? It doesn't works even if I put table1.id = 1 instead...

Comment: . . Is the query in the question the real query you are running?  You might try putting up an example on SQL Fiddle to see if the problem can be replicated.